# Objective-c nib view Mainview autolayout

Tags: objective-c, view, autolayout, constraints, nib

I have created a nib view, and add the constraints with interface builder (use autolayout and use size classes is checked).

When I call it in the mainStoryboard the behavior is not applied.

Can someone suggest me a tutorial or code example how can I achieve my task ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add more code please ? Add your UIViewController's initialization code

Comment: In my UIViewController´s i have not added code. Only in the storyBoard i added a UIView in the View of the ViewController, and i have assigned its class to be the class of the nib View